# how to connect my page to the database

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

i am trying to do registration page so when the user fill the fields, the information should go to the database but it keeps showing me this:

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bawazir\Untitled-1.php on line 92

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

here is the code :

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bawazir\Untitled-1.php on line 92

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: sorry for not showing you the codes , here it is :

Comment: post relevant code

Answer (score 0):

`"Notice: Undefined variable: sql ... "` means that you are trying to use a variable that doesn't exist or is not defined at that moment.

Try defining the `$sql` variable at the beginning of the file where your database connection is.

Answer (score 0):

> Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bawazir\Untitled-1.php on line 92

That code above means that you are trying to use a variable before it actually has a value in it. You need to make sure $sql has a value when it is being used.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

That means that your used credentials are wrong and the connection to the database is refused. Make sure you use the right credentials that you have set in phpMyadmin.